# Htaccess accessing outside of the current directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my web root I have a .htaccess which uses a RewriteRule, for example:

RewriteRule ^/t/([0-9]+)/$ ../list.php?id=$1 [L]

Is this correct if list.php is in the folder below the current one? I can't find any information about this and it's currently not working, so I'm not sure whether it is either possible, or I am doing it wrong.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: I've not alteast got something happening: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ ../test.php [L]

Comment: This atleast gives me 400 Bad Request. Does this give anyone more info to help me?

Answer (score 0):

The second path don't care about "current folder" as it starts after the host.

Comment: So you're saying everything that htaccess accesses has to be from the / ?

Comment: But if it's from the / coudldn't ../list.php move backwards?

Comment: Can't you test ? Yeah it will move backwards but be careful ("Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.")

Comment: I will have more of a play but it isn't working at the moment. I just wanted to check it was possible before I wasted time on it. Thanks.